# Kingfisher check for 404 status

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, kingfisher

I'm using the following call to download an image using KingFisher.
This works fine but the problem is that `sddefault.jpg` is not available on all the videos and I have to use instead `hqdefault.jpg`. I get a 404 status from the server but how do I check for this status if it's 404 or 200?

My Code:

```
self.searchResult.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/\(String(describing: video.yt_id!))/sddefault.jpg"))
```

Comment: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#with-a-completion-handler Use the version with a `completionHandler` that returns an `NSError` and so you can have the error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much something like this, not sure if KF has the same method but basically the completion block is what's after "completed: { }"

```
self.searchResult.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: photo_url), completed: { (image: UIImage?, error: Error?, cache, url) in
                if error != nil {
                    self.imgSharedUser.image = self.user_image
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :

```
KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: url, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
    print(image)
    print(error)
     print(imageURL )

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the version of `setImage` that takes a completion block. One of the parameters is an error that will tell you why it failed.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific please?